# A Newton-like identity

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, sequences-and-series

Let $\xi_1, \xi_2, \cdots, \xi_n$ be
indeterminates. Define the following indeterminates:
$$s_k :=
\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\xi_i^k, 1\le k <\infty ,$$
 $$\sigma_k :=
\sum\limits_{1\le i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_k\le n}\xi_{i_1}\xi_{i_1}\cdots\xi_{i_k}, 1\le k <\infty.$$

How to show  $$ \prod\limits_{i=1}^n(1-\xi_it)=1-\sigma_1t+\sigma_2t^2-\cdots+(-1)^n\sigma_nt^n=\exp\left(-\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty s_j\frac{t^j}{j}\right)?$$

Thanks.

Comment: The left side is simple foiling... The right side... hmm what is $s_j$?

Comment: @user9176: It is defined in line two of the post.

Comment: Ups, I probably need new glasses. For the right side, plug in $s_j$ and use the Taylor series of $\ln$ ;)

Comment: @user9176: why not post an answer? :-)

Comment: @user9176: I think my English is quite okay for a non-native speaker but until a few days ago I wouldn't have had the slightest clue what "the left side is simple *preventing something undesirable to happen*" could possibly mean. Anyone outside the US/Schaum-system would be similarly stumped.

Comment: You'll want to see page 427 of [Charalambides's book](http://books.google.com/books?id=PDMGA-v5G54C&pg=PA427).

Comment: @t.b. `Foiling' is an affectionate term for distributing.  The name comes from expansion of two binomials: in the case of $(a+b)(c+d)$, the expanded product is the sum $ac+ad+bc+bd$, i.e. First, Inner, Outer, Last.

Comment: @AWalker: Thanks! As I said, the first time I saw that was [a few days ago](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77606/) and [I found out a few minutes later](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/36?m=2309330#2309330) :)

Comment: @t.b.: If it's any consolation, I find the acronyms most of my students use that are related to math just as confusing  (I'm also not a native speaker either). And I positively dislike "FOIL" and its many derivations. As far as I can tell, it actually makes students *unable* to expand products unless they happen to be binomial times binomial...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The power series of the logarithm gives

$$\log (1-\xi t) = -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \xi^k \frac{t^k}{k}.$$

Summing this identity for the different values of $\xi$ and then taking the exponential gives the desired identity.